# CSS and pure JS custom cursor expand on hover

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a CSS and JS based custom cursor, which I want to expand when hovering on certain elements. I understand that specificity seems to be my problem, but I'm not sure what exactly I'm doing wrong. From what I understand, the `+` should select something that does not share the same parent object as the `:hover` object

```js
/*kinda laggy cursor control js */
const cursor = document.querySelector('.cursor');
document.addEventListener('mousemove', e => {
  cursor.setAttribute("style", "top: " + e.pageY + "px; left: " + e.pageX + "px;")
})

const cursor2 = document.querySelector('.cursor2');
document.addEventListener('mousemove', e => {
  cursor2.setAttribute("style", "top: " + e.pageY + "px; left: " + e.pageX + "px;")
})
```

```css
.cursor {
  width: 25px;
  height: 25px;
  position: absolute;
  border: 2px solid rgb(41, 41, 41);
  border-radius: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  transition: 50ms;
  transition-timing-function: ;
  mix-blend-mode: difference;
  z-index: 200;
  pointer-events: none;
}

.cursor2 {
  z-index: 200;
  transition: 10ms;
  width: 5px;
  height: 5px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background-color: black;
  pointer-events: none;
  mix-blend-mode: difference;
  position: absolute;
  transition-timing-function: ;
}

.inner {
  font-family: 'Helvetica';
  font-size: calc(2em + 8vw);
  font-weight: 700;
  -webkit-text-fill-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
  -webkit-text-stroke: 1px;
  -webkit-text-stroke-color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
  letter-spacing: -.6vw;
  line-height: calc(.7em + 1vw);
  animation: marquee 30s linear infinite;
  display: inline-block;
  user-select: none;
}

a {
  text-decoration: none;
  cursor: none;
}

a:hover+.cursor {
  transform: scale(1.5);
  !important transition-duration: 500ms;
}
```

```html
<div class="inner">
  <span class="switcher about use"><a href="html/about/about.html">about</a></span><br>
</div>



<!-- outer cursor div-->
<div class="cursor">
</div>
<!-- inner cursor div-->
<div class="cursor2">
</div>
```

The question, is why `a:hover+.cursor{}` does not affect the cursor at all. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: It doesn't affect because `a` is a child of  `.inner`. +  is an adjacent sibling combinator. `a` and `.cursor` should have the same parent for that purpose. If you do `.inner:hover+.cursor{}` you will see it works. So in your case, I will toggle a class with `js` if you don't want to change your markdown.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can work with the `+`, if they are direct siblings. So put your cursor inside the span, then it's working :)

```
<div class="inner">
  <span class="switcher about use"><a href="html/about/about.html">about</a>
     <div class="cursor"></div>
  </span><br>
</div>
```

Comment: That does indeed work, but the issue is this is a global cursor, and I can't really put it inside that <div> as I've got a container for inner as well, with more transforms in that. Is there any other method you would reccomend?